# plotting a Monte Carlo simulation in R

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, montecarlo, coin-flipping

I am trying to create a plot that graph a Monte Carlo simulation of a coin toss with iterations on x and probability on y. However, I am having difficulty creating the necessary function.

So far I have

```
set.seed(2738952)
coins<-function(n){
    sample(c(0,1),n,replace=TRUE)
}
mean(coins(10000)==1)

ggplot(mapping = aes(x=iteration,y=coins))+geom_line()
```

> Error: Aesthetics must be valid data columns. Problematic aesthetic(s): y = coins. Did you mistype the name of a data column or forget to add stat()?

I am unsure how to create the iterations as well as the probability.

Comment: What do you want the plot to look like? You say `x = iteration`, but you don't define iteration.... presumably `iteration = seq_along(coins)`. And ggplot likes to plot *data in data frames*, so you should create a data frame. Your `coins` are either 1 or 0 is that what you want on the y axis? And when you say "probability on y", what do you mean by that? The mean so far? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

Is this something you're looking for?

```r
iterations <- 100
flip_results <- coins(iterations)
# As @teunbrand suggested, use cumsum to avoid looping
pct_head <- pct_head <- cumsum(flip_results) / seq_len(iterations)
ggplot(mapping = aes(x=1:iterations,y=pct_head))+geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: Alternatively, for the anti-loop mobs: `pct_head <- cumsum(flip_results) / seq_len(iterations)`